# Swift : Error on value of type 'Data' to type 'Data'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, camera, ios-camera

I have some function for Camera using AVKit and AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate.

```
import UIKit 
import AVKit

class CaptureImageClass: NSObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

    var photoData: Data?

    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {

        if let error = error {
            print("Error capturing photo: \(error)")
        } else {
            photoData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() //Cannot assign value of type 'Data?' to type 'Data?'
        }
    }

    func capture(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishCaptureForResolvedSettings resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, error: Error?) {
        guard let photoData = photoData else {
            print("No photo data resource")
            return
        }
        let capturedImage = UIImage.init(data: photoData , scale: 1.0) //Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type 'Data'
        if let image = capturedImage {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

this code compiled without problem when i make standalone project. But when i try to apply to another project, it have some error like `Cannot assign value of type 'Data?' to type 'Data?'` and  `Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type 'Data'`
Is this problem caused by diffrent Swift version or not?

Note:
this "another project" deployment target is iOS 10 & swift 3 and using `func capture` for `didFinishCaptureForResolvedSettings` and cant using `func photoOutput`
My standalone project is running using Swift 4 and for the deployment target is iOS 11.3

Comment: Do you have another type named `Data` defined somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using
    func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput,
                 didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,
                 previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,
                 resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings,
                 bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?,
                 error: Error?) {

```
    // Make sure we get some photo sample buffer
    guard error == nil,
        let photoSampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer else {
            print("Error capturing photo: \(String(describing: error))")
            return
    }
    // Convert photo same buffer to a jpeg image data by using // AVCapturePhotoOutput
    guard let imageData =
        AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: photoSampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewPhotoSampleBuffer) else {
            return
    }

    let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: imageData as CFData)

    let cgImageRef = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.absoluteColorimetric)


    let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the error is not caused by the iOS version of your device.

Keep in mind that

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, 
didFinishProcessingPhoto 
photo: AVCapturePhoto, 
error: Error?) {
```

Is available for iOS11 and later for iOS10 and earlier you should use

```
optional func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput,
 didFinishProcessingPhoto photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,
previewPhoto previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,
resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, 
bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, 
error: Error?)
```

Also

```
fileDataRepresentation()
```

Is available for iOS11 and later

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Someone has override the `Data` type. You can bypass this using :

`var photoData: Swift.Data?`